# Recovery files possible after being overwritten by Ubuntu install?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, fat32

Good evening,

Unfortunately I used a data-containing USB-drive with the Ubuntu 22.04 Installer ISO. This was of course a very stupid action and I want to see if I somehow can turn back this stupidity. I don't have anything against Ubuntu, my recently installed server is running Ubuntu (hence the overwriting).

The USB-stick was formatted either FAT32 or NTFS and contained data that I would like to get back. Is there any way to accomplish this?

My Windows-laptop can't read the drive and wants to format it first. My Ubuntu-server can see partitions, but I didn't try to recover anything, as I don't know software for that and last my Mac sees the partitions, but doesn't know what to do with it.

HELP !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Your details are unclear; you mention a release (22.04) and installer (*but not which as there are multiple installers for 22.04 chosen by the ISO used*) and a USB drive. When an ISO is written to thumb-drive; it's either *burnt* (*meaning all prior data on USB drive is lost; this process makes it bootable*) or just copied (*written into free space so no data gets overwritten*) but you gave no clues as to what you actually did; what software & options in that software was used. It's unclear to me where you actually are & are actually asking to recover, as I don't know what you did sorry.

Comment: How big is the usb drive?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I missed your comments. I'll answer both questions. The image I burnt on the USB drive is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish), making it a bootable installation USB. The size of the USB-drive is 128GB.